# Trimming Request.Body before reaching action method, for model binding in XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Ethernet to 1-Wire interface that periodically sends out an HTTP post with sensors data. The data body is in XML, except it's not fully valid XML. I can not change the HTTP body because it's in an embedded software. The complete request body looks like this:

```
 ------------------------------3cbec9ce8f05
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ServerData"; filename="details.xml"
 Content-Type: text/plain

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Devices-Detail-Response xmlns="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <PollCount>2739</PollCount>
 <DevicesConnected>1</DevicesConnected>
 <LoopTime>1.022</LoopTime>
 <DevicesConnectedChannel1>0</DevicesConnectedChannel1>
 <DevicesConnectedChannel2>0</DevicesConnectedChannel2>
 <DevicesConnectedChannel3>1</DevicesConnectedChannel3>
 <DataErrorsChannel1>0</DataErrorsChannel1>
 <DataErrorsChannel2>0</DataErrorsChannel2>
 <DataErrorsChannel3>0</DataErrorsChannel3>
 <VoltageChannel1>4.91</VoltageChannel1>
 <VoltageChannel2>4.92</VoltageChannel2>
 <VoltageChannel3>4.92</VoltageChannel3>
 <VoltagePower>5.16</VoltagePower>
 <DeviceName>Unit 3 OW2</DeviceName>
 <HostName>EDSOWSERVER2</HostName>
 <MACAddress>00:00:00:00:00:00</MACAddress>
 <DateTime>2018-12-12 16:44:48</DateTime>
 <owd_DS18B20 Description="Programmable resolution thermometer">
 <Name>DS18B20</Name>
 <Family>28</Family>
 <ROMId>F70000024D85E528</ROMId>
 <Health>7</Health>
 <Channel>3</Channel>
 <RawData>C6004B467FFF0A102A00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</RawData>
 <PrimaryValue>12.3750 Deg C</PrimaryValue>
 <Temperature Units="Centigrade">12.3750</Temperature>
 <UserByte1 Writable="True">75</UserByte1>
 <UserByte2 Writable="True">70</UserByte2>
 <Resolution>12</Resolution>
 <PowerSource>0</PowerSource>
 </owd_DS18B20>
 </Devices-Detail-Response>

 ------------------------------3cbec9ce8f05--
```

So i'm trying to remove the '--------...' and Content-Type, and the '-------..' at the end before it hits the action method.

Here's my controller:

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 using Monitor.Models;
 using System;
 using System.IO;

 namespace Monitor.Controllers
 {
     [ApiController]
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
     public class SensorController : Controller
     {
         private readonly ILogger _log;

         public SensorController(ILogger<SensorController> logger)
         {
             _log = logger;
         }

         [HttpPost]
         [OwServer]
         public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Ow_ServerModel model)
         {
             return Ok("Working");
         }
     }

     public class OwServer : Attribute, IResourceFilter
     {
         public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
         {
             context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/xml";

             using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body))
             {
                 string body = stream.ReadToEnd();

                 int start = body.IndexOf('<');
                 int last = body.LastIndexOf('>') + 1;

                 string parsedBody = body.Substring(start, (last - start));


                 // context.HttpContext.Request.Body = 
             }

         }

         public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
         {
         }
     }
 }


 using System;
 using System.Xml.Serialization;

 namespace Monitor.Models
 {
     [Serializable]
     [XmlRoot("Devices-Detail-Response", Namespace = "http://www.example.com")]
     public class Ow_ServerModel
     {
         public int PollCount { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request body indicates that the embedded software is posting a multipart data. And the following `content-disposition` means that it's sending a file of `details.xml`:

```
------------------------------3cbec9ce8f05
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ServerData"; filename="details.xml"
Content-Type: text/plain
```

So you don't need to manually remove the boundary of '------------------------------3cbec9ce8f05' and `Content-Type=...`.  **Simply use `Request.Form.Files`.**

Also, as suggested by [@ivan-valadares](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53754110/10091607), you can use a Model binder to lift the heavy things . But it seems that he is treating all the request body as string and then construct an `XDocument` . A much more elegant way is use `XmlSerializer` to create a strongly-typed object. Also, [IModelBinder Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.imodelbinder?view=aspnetcore-2.1) doesn't have a method of `public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)`. We should use `BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)` instead.

So create a model binder as below :

```
public class EmbededServerDataBinder<T> : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext)); }
        var modelName = bindingContext.BinderModelName ?? "ServerData";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var data= bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[modelName];
        if(data == null){ 
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName,"invalid error");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        using(var stream = data.OpenReadStream()){
            var o = serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(o);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in the Action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([ModelBinder(typeof(EmbededServerDataBinder<Ow_ServerModel>))] Ow_ServerModel ServerData)
    {
        return Ok("Working");
    }
```

Note the name of `ServerData` matters. The model binder will seek this name within content-disposition.

I test it with your payload , and it works as expected for me :

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks! I did not know how the file looks in a http request, which makes a lot of sense

Comment: @itminus just one note : public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) is the modelbinder for WebapiController and BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext) is for the MVC Controller, i thought in this case was webapi because of [ApiController] [Route("api/[controller]")] but i didn't saw the extend " : Controller" instead of ": ApiController". in that case dont forget to register the Modelbinder in global.asax :  ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(XDocument), new XmlCustomBinder());

Comment: @IvanValadares Hi, I'm afraid that you didn't notice that the OP is using `ASP.NET Core` instead of ASP.NET ( Classic )

Comment: did not, webapicontroller does not exists anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do that with a ActionFilter, i would recomend a custom Binder and the use of regex to extract de xml from the request.

Register the new custom xml binder in WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0,
    new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(XDocument), new XmlCustomBinder()));
}
```

Create a custom binder that will get the content body and extract only the xml

```
public class XmlCustomBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var parsedXml = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"<\?xml.*>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            Match match = regex.Match(parsedXml);
            if (!match.Success) return false;
            parsedXml = match.Groups[0].Value;
            TextReader textReader = new StringReader(parsedXml);
            XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(textReader);
            bindingContext.Model = xDocument;
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("XmlCustomBinder", ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller code, get a XDocument (XML) value

```
[HttpPost]
[OwServer]
public IActionResult Post([ModelBinder(typeof(XmlCustomBinder))] XDocument xDocument)
{
     return Ok("Working");
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.7.2